# Julia: unintended extension of base functions

Tags: julia

I have the following, incomplete Julia code:

```
mutable struct Env
end

function step(env, action:UInt32)
    return ones(8), 1.0, true, Dict()
end

function reset(env)
    return ones(8)
end
```

When I try to use it, I get the following errors:

> LoadError: error in method definition: function Base.step must be
>   explicitly imported to be extended
>   LoadError: error in method definition: function Base.reset must be
>   explicitly imported to be extended

I don't know what Base.step and Base.reset are, and I don't want to extend them.

Is there some way for me to keep these function names without extending the base functions? If I do just extend the base functions with my completely unrelated methods, are there going to be problems?

I really do not want to change the names of my functions because I want to keep them in line with the [OpenAI Gym](https://gym.openai.com/docs/) API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define them inside a module like this

```
module Gym

mutable struct Env
end

function step(env, action::UInt32)
    return ones(8), 1.0, true, Dict()
end

function reset(env)
    return ones(8)
end

end
```

Then you can call them directly as `step` and `reset` inside the module. Outside the module you have to qualify them like this: `Gym.step` and `Gym.reset`.

Additionally - note that you get this problem only after you introduce `step` and `reset` in `Main` module before trying to extend them (e.g. by calling or referencing them). So when starting a clean Julia session this will work:

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.0.2 (2018-11-08)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> step(x) = x
step (generic function with 1 method)
```

but this will fail:

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.0.2 (2018-11-08)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> step
step (generic function with 4 methods)

julia> step(x) = x
ERROR: error in method definition: function Base.step must be explicitly imported to be extended
```